# How to restore accidentally deleted windows boot partition?

Tags: boot, partitioning, bios, grub

I was trying to convert my Windows 10 system to UEFI from BIOS using [MBR2GPT](https://www.maketecheasier.com/convert-legacy-bios-uefi-windows10/#How-to-Convert-Legacy-BIOS-to-UEFI)  and got a message:

> cannot create uefi partition error 0x000036B7

Now when I'm trying to boot I see:

> error: no such partition.  
> Entering the rescue mode...  
> grub rescue>_

I checked the disk on another pc and it shows boot partition as an unallocated space.
Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Why not use the last disk image... just restore the boot partition only.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Windows boot media or a Recovery Disk,
[Run a Startup Repair in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

As long as your Windows partition is unharmed, this will
only repair the boot, including the UEFI partition.